# Passing PHP array to JAVASCRIPT (issue)

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

There's some weird issue it seems.
I'm trying to pass a php array to js, which I've accomplished. I can display the array size like so

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (jarr.length);
```

and it works perfectly fine, however, when I try to display a value in said array, it says `object Object`
and what's weird is if I go try to read a value which isnt stored, for example jarr[234] it says undefined because there's no value stored, so I know some data is being transferred.

Any help?

edit: here's how I passed the array to js

```
var jarr = <?php echo json_encode($testing); ?>;
```

edit: I forgot the remove the parse part before copying it, I was experimenting beforehand.

Comment: Why are you trying to JSON.parse() a number? As for _"when I try to display a value in said array, it says object Object"_ well you need to show that code. But I would guess you are trying to display an object through something that is only meant to have strings passed / assigned to it

Comment: From the edit, it's clear that you already have an object, there's no need to parse that, but you can't pass it directly to `innerHTML` either, unless it's a primitive

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove the "parse" part before copying and pasting (there was something previous there). How do I pass the string from an array slow to html then? And yes the array is storing strings.

Comment: To show the entire array: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jarr);` To show a single string: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = jarr[0];`

Comment: can you var_dump ($testing ); whats inside it

Comment: yes var_dump displays the correct information :)

Comment: can you show the sample of var_dump

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just directly use `jarr` without parsing it, for example:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = jarr.length;
document.getElementById("first_element").innerHTML = jarr.length > 0 ? jarr[0] : "empty array";
```

If you are doing the above and the elements are showing up as `object Object` it means that inside your array, you are storing objects rather than primitive data types. So maybe try something like the following to generate a nice string representation of those objects (noting that this is needed for displaying them, but not for using them directly in your JavaScript code):

```
document.getElementById("first_element").innerHTML = jarr.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(jarr[0]) : "empty array";
```

Comment: Doesn't really change anything.
 
sorry I forgot to remove the "parse" part before copying and pasting (there was something previous there).

Comment: still says [object Object] like I put in my post.

Answer (score 0):

What Chris said fixed the issue!

"To show the entire array: document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jarr); To show a single string: document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = jarr[0]; – Chris G 7 mins ago 
"
For whatever reason adding the (stringify) fixes it for me. 
An example

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jarr[2].title);
```

Comment: For whatever reason? It's simple: Since `jarr[x]` is apparently an Object,  setting it as `.innerHTML` calls its `.toString()` (producing `[object Object]`). JSON.stringify however takes an Object and turns it into JSON, which is precisely what we need to print the actual contents of an Object. However: if `jarr[2].title` is a String, you *do not* need it.

Comment: Also, you said "the array is storing strings", but it's actually storing Objects (which contain Strings). That's why Flight Odyssey's answer didn't work for you.